# Output menu navigation in php file

Tags: menus, templates

I have a WordPress site which generates a menu at the top of the page with this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

This line is located somewhere in a file called `header.php`.

(Location in wp-admin is: `Appearance -> Editor -> Templates -> Header (header.php)`

What i need to do is use the line i gave earlier:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

In a separate php file. So that when i navigate to: `http://mijnwpsite.com/justthemenu.php

That it only outputs the menu. No doctype or anything.

What steps do i have to take for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would require the path to `wp-blog-header.php` to access WordPress functionality in a 
standalone PHP file. So your `justthemenu.php` file should contain the following code.

```
<?php
    require('/wp-blog-header.php');
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) );
?>
```